# How to hide path in lstlistoflistings?

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, lists, paths

When I am making a list of listings in my latex report, using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language = Matlab,
inputpath=./Code/}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings
\lstinputlisting{test1.m}
\lstinputlisting{test2.m}
\lstinputlisting{test3.m}

\end{document}
```

the paths of my files are displayed:

[image]

How can I hide the path? I would like to obtain:

[image]

without moving my files into the current directory.

Comment: You may be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option `caption` enhances the listing with a caption, whose title is also used for the entry in the list of listings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language = Matlab, inputpath=./Code/}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings
\lstinputlisting[caption=test1.m]{test1.m}
\lstinputlisting[caption=test2.m]{test2.m}
\lstinputlisting[caption=test3.m]{test3.m}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The caption can be suppressed for the document by an empty mandatory argument for key `caption`. The optional argument in square brackets denotes the title for the entry in the list of listings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language = Matlab, inputpath=./Code/}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings
\lstinputlisting[caption={[test1.m]{}}]{test1.m}
\lstinputlisting[caption={[test2.m]{}}]{test2.m}
\lstinputlisting[caption={[test3.m]{}}]{test3.m}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works well. I still have another problem with the caption though: for a file called "test_name.m", the command `\lstinputlisting{test_name.m}` works but neither `\lstinputlisting[caption={[test_name.m]{}}]{test_name.m}` nor `\lstinputlisting[caption={[test\_name.m]{}}]{test_name.m}` work. How can I add the underscore character?

Comment: @fidekild put the filename in `" "`

Comment: @fidekild `\_` (or `\textunderscore`) in the value of `caption` works.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thank you, it now works perfectly.